# Application approved - pending developer release - Currently unavailable in your Country

Tags: ios, air, app-store, app-store-connect, release

I have created an Application for the iOS app Store. It was approved and now waiting for my release. In iTunes connect, i made sure to select all Countries when it comes to availability.

On my itunesConnect app, if i select my App and tap on "View on App Store", it will take me to the store and say " This app is currently unavailable in your country's store, but available in the U.S Store "

My question is, when i do release the app, my goal is to have it available on all stores, so am i getting this error now because it's not released yet or did i mess anything up inside the file?

The app was created using Flash CS6 - Adobe air

Comment: It will be available in app store only if u release the app. PS: It may take sometime to reflect in app store after manual release.

Comment: @Venkat yes exactly, so u mean it will be available in all stores and i'm getting this error now because it's not release yet?

Comment: Yes exactly....

Comment: @Venkat thank you, post it as an answer so i could approve it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It says, **"Apple has approved your application/build, you need to release your application build for public use (or available publically)"**

Here is ref document from apple, what it says, about this:

> **[Pending Developer Release](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html)**
>   
> Your app version has been approved by Apple and is waiting on you to release it.
>   Release the version to the store when you’re ready. See [Specifying When App Versions Are Released](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH14-SW2).

**[How to release your build](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html)**

Follow these steps to release your build:

1. Login into your Apple Developer Account and Select your App
2. Now select your most recent application version (which is showing a version name with status.
3. Scroll page to 'Version Release' section and process for build release.

Here is sample snapshot (from Apple):

[image]

Edit according to query from OP:

**Will my app become available for my country also, if I release it on App store? It is not currently released and when I click on link 'View on App Store', it is showing me an error, " *It's not available in your country's store*"** 

**Answer:** Yes, It will show your app in for your country also, if you've selected (not deselected/skipped) from list of all countries.

You can find list of countries here and skip any if you want, by deselecting it:

In your iTune Accoun: (Go To) >> Pricing and Availability >> See 'Territory Availability'

[image]

Sample list of available countries:

**Note:** Your profile says, your current country is 'Lebanon' and it is allowed by Apple on App Store, see below snapshot

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer, i know how to release the app. My question is, Now through the itunesconnect app, i get the option to see the app on the store even if it's not released. I know that there is nothing to see, and i do expect to get an error with no item on the Store, and i knw it will change as soon as i release it. But i was worried that the error stated " it's not available in your country's store" , and i was asking as soon as i release it, it will be available to all stores regardless this error?

Comment: I got you.. See an updated answer... And sorry my initial post was useless without this edit.

Comment: perfect thank you so much! one last thing before i mark it as the response, the availability of the app is only chosen in the window you showed, and nothing to do with adobe air / flash...? @Krunal

Comment: Yes, follow it as I've shown here. Can you brief me, what would be role of Adobe Air/Flash? I've never used it during App release process.. (I've release around 48 apps on store.)

Comment: i've released some sort a close number through xcode. But since it's my first app through flash, i was wondering if there's anything i should include in the sent ipa to incude all countries or is only done through the itunes portal?

Comment: No, iPA does not decide country list, So you may not need to worry about the it. And you can change it manually from developer account.

Comment: Thank you so much!]

Answer (score 1):

It is important to know that if you choose to make a pre-sale, you must cancel to release the app on the App Store.

-> Go to Pricing and Availability;
-> Uncheck the option to do a pre-sale.

Answer (score 0):

Its means your app version has been approved by Apple, but you still need to release it for sale.

All app Statuses are explained here, follow up link:

https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev18557d60e