# Distribute iOS app for specific region/territory

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, itunes-app, app-distribution

I am about to release my App, just waiting for my Apple Developer to come in.

Can I decide the countries where my app will be available to download from? Or will I only be able to choose one single country/whole Europe/World?

Say I wanted to make my app available in Europe but not in Portugal - Is that possible?.......

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to limit the countries an iOS application is released to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694280/possible-to-limit-the-countries-an-ios-application-is-released-to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course you can enable/disable (make your app available for) specific regions (countries).

As you want to disable you app for `Portugal`...

`Portugal` is listed in territory list in iTune account for app. Just uncheck (remove tickmark) for that country.

Look at this snapshot:

[image]

Here is more detailed answer (how you can see territories/list) -
 [Application approved - pending developer release - Currently unavailable in your Country](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47131773/application-approved-pending-developer-release-currently-unavailable-in-your/47135092#47135092)

Answer (score 8):

Follow my steps in iTunes store to update territory:

```
   1) Open Pricing and Availability
    2) Click on Edit on Availability

    You can tick mark only those territories in which you want your application.
```

[image: Step: 1]

[image: Step: 2]

[image: Step: 3]

Comment: Can I change territory for Ready for sale app in this way? or I can set territory before review only.

Comment: You can change it after sale as well.

Comment: I have changed the territories when the app is Ready for Sale. The change is not reflected on the App store. It's been more than 10 hrs. Do I have to submit another version for these changes to reflect.

Comment: No, sometimes it will take a time to load. Mean time, apple has chrismas holiday. I guess, you need to wait.

Comment: Make sure your apps are up to date and ready for the holidays. New apps and app updates will not be accepted December 23–27 (Pacific Time), so any releases should be scheduled, submitted, and approved in advance. Other App Store Connect features will remain available.