# Submit app to App Store with password protection

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval, account, submission

I recently updated an app for a client and it's now ready for submission to the App Store. But after a talk with my client they told me that the previous version (not developed or submitted by me) had a kind of "password protection" on the App Store. They explained it as anyone could find the app on App Store but when you click "download" the user would need to enter a password (not the Apple ID password, more of a predefined password specifically for this app) to continue the download process.

I am used to submitting apps to the App Store, both paid and free, but I have never done this and don't honestly know how. My closest guess is that we need to upgrade the plan to an enterprise account, but from my understanding (and please correct me if I'm wrong) this will remove the app from the App Store search and only allow download from a link or file?

What way would you guys recommend?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There's no recommendation.

What you think and whatever is running in your mind is completely correct. There's no way to set custom download passwords. The only way to download using appstore is to use the apple id.

Point your client to the apple guidelines and documentation's. Hopefully they should understand.

Answer (score 1):

Very nice concern from security point of view but unfortunately Apple has not provided any such feature yet...

An alternate solution to your query:

You can't block user from downloading your app but you can block user from using you app with the help of AppLock feature (One time password authentication - when user uses your app for first time).

Set a Passcode/Pattern protected lock screen as a first/main screen of your application (immediately after Splash Scree) and only users can unlock your app, to whom you've shared passcode. (Note: Integrate passcode verification using web service/server, so you can reset passcode any time from server)

[image]

I hope this may be helpful to you...

#### Update

Here is more option, if you want to allow/restrict your app usage for specific region/country (listed on Store).

- [Distribute iOS app for specific region/territory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47710547/distribute-ios-app-for-specific-region-territory/47711671#47711671)

Comment: This was my original thought but for some unexplainable reason the client did not want this...

Comment: I can provide you valid reason why should you implement this logic for app security, if you can share client arguments against this option

Comment: Ideally you should never have to use this. If you want to restrict users from using an app, create an enterprise account distribute within the people who want to use it. Sharing an application with enterprise account is the same as sharing the password or pattern for the application.

Comment: @Harsh - You are absolutely right.. but OP has one argument - "He wants his app on App store" and I think in that case, this should be only an option. I posted this concept/answer by considering a specific requirement of OP

Comment: Both of you are correct and I'm thankful for your answers. The main reason that the client want the app on the App Store is for simplicity. There are several hundreds of salesmen that are going to use this app and most of them have small- or nonexistent technical knowledge BUT they know how to download an app from the App Store... As I have never submitted an app from an enterprise account I don't know how the distribution takes place, but I guess its more advanced than downloading the app from the App Store.

Comment: @Pointblaster - Ohh dear, you could ask us, how to deploy an enterprise app, then, we definitely help you. Since 5 years I've been working on Enterprise apps only.. You can use website of client's business domain to provide an Enterprise app link to your app users with password protected web page/application.

Comment: Wait, so distribution with enterprise is a as simple as sharing a link? What more is needed? (to be clear-> I understand that the submission is more than sharing a link, Im talking about the distribution to the salespeople)